# command not found issue with .sh

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, dropbox

I want to create a .sh script, which is calling another .sh with variable.

If I put below script into terminal, it executes perfectly.

```
~/Dropbox/dropboxignore.sh genupi ~/Dropbox/
```

and this line is also working too directly via terminal.

```
dropboxignore genupi ~/Dropbox/
```

But if I put any of above command into another ".sh", it shows below error as expected.

```
~/Dropbox/dropboxignore_sync.sh: command not found
```

below is my new ".sh"

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
~/Dropbox/dropboxignore.sh genupi ~/Dropbox/
```

Will be very appreciate if anyone could help on this.

Comment: POSIX shell does not understand `~`.  Can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to your PATH settings.

POSIX shell does not understand `~`.  You could run your script by bash or zsh, if it is written to be compatible for one of these shells, i.e.

```
zsh ~/Dropbox/dropboxignore.sh genupi ~/Dropbox/
```

or

```
bash ~/Dropbox/dropboxignore.sh genupi ~/Dropbox/
```

(I can assume that the calling script already runs in a suitable shell; otherwise you would have got the error already for `dropboxignore.sh`).

Since you did not show us the complete content of dropboxignore.sh, I can't say whether zsh or bash will work, or whether both are fine; but at least the author of dropboxignore.sh should know which shell he had in mind.

Another possibility is of course to add a suitable `#!` line to dropboxignore.sh, to ensure that it is called by the correct shell.

Comment: the bash seems still not working well.
The dropboxignore.sh is actually from other github source.
https://github.com/sp1thas/dropboxignore

Comment: thanks, I think it works again with "bash". But not sure why the first few times it didn't work.

Comment: In case you have in the future problems with bash, please always put a `echo $BASH_VERSION` right before that statement in your script which produces the error. This helps others to support you, in that we can verify that the code is indeed executed by bash.